# Android touchevent--- need help/suggestion according to scenario

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, touch-event, android-imageview

Now I have an ImageView and its a circle which is at the slightly  below than center position (But this should not matter).

I have written code  onTouch of ImageView for ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_UP ,now  consider  as user have put finger on circle and move and move.... I want to active some code when user move finger and exceed the region of CIRCLE image(As soon as user exceed the region the code should be ececuted onlly once)

Here is my code

```
ImageView view1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fccircledetectionarea);

      view1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
      {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fccircledetectionarea);
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                final float x=imageView.getTop();


                Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "Top Position:"+x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "Over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "Over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I cannot archive my goal through ACTION_MOVE: as it start to work if user move finger within the circle

***And my second query*** is that How to set alpha of this imageview I have used

```
view1.setAlpha(0);
```

But  is not working and I have also made this imageview invisible but than my onTouch code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Within your `onTouch` method record a boolean to check if the user is touching within the bounds of the circle.

```
boolean inCircle = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= circleRadius
```

Where x is taken from `event.getX() - circleCenterX` and y is taken from `event.getY() - circleCenterY` (touch position's offset from center of the circle)

Comment: but the circle is image I have not draw it manually...How to get center of an imageview

Comment: You can take the width and height of the ImageView and half them.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, but can you please explain how,,,     boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) -->works

Comment: taking the center of the circle as the origin, this gives you the distance of a point from the center and if this is less than or equal to the radius of the circle then it must be within the circle

Comment: ok thank you very much I have done on paper and it seems your trick will work for me ....tomorrow i will implement it and let you know thank you  very much!!!!!

Comment: I cant implement  something like 'if (touch > imageView.getHeight() or imageView.getWidth())'{my code} something like this

Comment: Depends if you want the behaviour to be within the ImageView or within the circle within the ImageView. You may also have to create a custom ImageView and override the onSizeChanged method to grab the dimensions.

Comment: Yeah if you print out the imageView.getHeight() or imageView.getWidth() in an onCreate, it won't return what you want. You'll need to create a custom view + override onSizeChanged method.

Comment: I did as u said and for finding center I used                 `int[] location = new int[2];
            imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

int radius=imageView.getHeight()/2;
                    int[] center=new int[2];
                    center[0]=location[0]+radius;
                    center[1]=location[1]+radius;
 ` but I am not getting desired  output  Is there anything I am doing wrong...

Comment: :My Imageview size is as same as the circle it contains and ...Your suggestion works on paper and it should work on implementation ,why it is not working I am not getting idea ------wether I am doing wrong in finding the center of the circle????

Comment: Or can I do something like ---> finger exceeds the image view size(portion of imageview)   and implement my ACTION_MOVE Code

Comment: Yes you can but it just won't be a circle region anymore.

Comment: how can I do that can you tell me please ??? and In any optimum way I want to achive my goal so which way would be best to do and how can I implement it