# How to get Center of an Imageview which is a circle

Tags: android, touch-event, android-imageview

Now I have an ImgeView which a circle and I want to find the center point of that circle so I have tried the following code but it seems not working

```
int[] location = new int[2];
            imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

int radius=imageView.getHeight()/2;
                    int[] center=new int[2];
                    center[0]=location[0]+radius;
                    center[1]=location[1]+radius;
```

so the coordinates I got by "location" is top point of the imageview or not ?

Please help me how to get a center point of an imageview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assumed below situation:

You will be loading an ImageView(either from  xml or code) and have a reference to the same in myImageView(say). Now, you wish to calculate the centre of the myImageView irrespective of its position on the screen.

If my assumption is correct then probably below is the solution you are looking for:

```
    int centerXOnImage=myImageView.getWidth()/2;
    int centerYOnImage=myImageView.getHeight()/2;

    int centerXOfImageOnScreen=myImageView.getLeft()+centerXOnImage;
    int centerYOfImageOnScreen=myImageView.getTop()+centerYOnImage;
```

Comment: But myImageView.getLeft() and myImageView.getTop() will give the position according to its parent ???

Comment: Actually I want to achieve the following link goal** [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676846/android-touchevent-need-help-suggestion-according-to-senario/6677836#6677836)** may be you can understand my problem more deeply

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top-left corner coordinates using:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Rect rect = iv.getDrawable().getRect();
int xOffset = rect.left;
int yOffset = rect.top;
```

Based on height/2 and width/2 you can establish the center of your ImageView .

Comment: I want the both x,y coordinates of center point and according to the whole  screen orientation because I have to consider the whole screen to work on center point of Imageview

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Chandan's answer,
say we are using the same code:

```
int centerXOnImage=myImageView.getWidth()/2;
int centerYOnImage=myImageView.getHeight()/2;

int centerXOfImageOnScreen=myImageView.getLeft()+centerXOnImage;
int centerYOfImageOnScreen=myImageView.getTop()+centerYOnImage;
```

if your `myImageView.getWidth()` is returning 0, you might want to do a little bit of modification:

```
myImageView.measure(0,0);
int centerXOnImage=myImageView.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
int centerYOnImage=myImageView.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
```

Notice, you might want to do this after myImageView is created in code and added to a root view.

Comment: myImageView.getHeight() always return 0. Why?